# Strange buffer shape when using planar buffer method

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, buffer, hydrography

I'm doing a very simple operation involving clipping some streams from the National Hydrography Dataset in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1, reprojecting them from "GCS North American 1983" into "USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area", and buffering the streams by 30 meters, with the following settings:
Distance = Linear unit, 30 meters
Side type = Full
End type = Round
Method = Planar
Dissolve type = All

The result is completely bizarre, like the following (note the blue is the "buffer", and the buffer-shaped white space around the streamlines is just that -- white space):[image]

The only way I can find to avoid this is to either change "Method" to "Geodesic" instead of "Planar", or to run the buffer operation on a stream file that is in a geographic rather than a projected coordinate system. But I don't see a need for using geodesic buffers when I'm working within a very small area and my stream file has a projected coordinate system. Moreover, this is the first time I've ever seen this kind of behavior. I've tested on many different clipped portions of the NHD and seen the same behavior, so it does not appear to be any kind of corruption of the polylines. Any ideas of what might be going on?

Comment: My goodness! Bizarre doesn't even begin to explain your results! I've been doing this for a *very* long time and I've seen nothing like that before. Perhaps use repair geometry on your watercourses to be sure there isn't an issue with the geometries. You shouldn't run a buffer on geographic data but the units will be accepted if you specify metres (meters) and Arc will use some *smoke and mirrors* approach to create the buffers so give it a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Glad to hear some confirmation of how odd this is. Never seen this in ten years. Just wanted to note that I did try "Repair Geometry" on numerous of my streamline samples w/o much luck. Was hoping to avoid having to buffer geographic data b/c of the decrease in speed -- plus just the fact that I don't understand why I should have to use it! But for some reason, it does successfully create buffers that look like ... buffers.

Comment: It's like the lines have turned themselves inside out; just out of curiosity what format are your buffers in? What do you get with dissolve=none? It could be some sort of weed tolerance for a super-large dataset - you might be better served using file geodatabase as the buffer storage, run sections at a time and dissolve in an edit session... that's kind of extreme but I think from what you've shown a fairly extreme method is needed.

Comment: I'm actually already writing to a file geodatabase (and the inputs are in that same geodatabase as well) and I'm running this on very small snippets of hydrography -- mostly so I can do the trial-&-error within a few seconds. Tried it numerous times with "none" dissolve and get the same sort of thing, although the odd irregular shapes and angles differ, with no discernible pattern in how.

Comment: I'm totally stumped.. Can you try in UTM (some zone), I think there's about 6 or 8 covering the US so that wouldn't necessarily be an ideal solution but would at least take care of one variable in the mix. I don't think it's a weed or grain tolerance as the whitespace is as detailed as I'd expect but the bizarre exo-polygons are somewhat less detailed. Buffering to a shapefile might also help remove another variable from the mix. Next stop is buffering using QGIS (don't laugh, it might be Arc that's the cause, would't be the first time, then at least you can submit a coherent support request).

Comment: Update: I could've sworn I'd already tried this before, but now when I write to shapefile instead of file geodatabase, all other things held equal, I can get correct buffers. I'd rather not have to do that, because ultimately I'm making thousands of separate little buffer files, so I wonder if there's some kind of geodatabase setting that's gone sour. But for now writing to shapefile mysteriously fixes it.

Comment: That sounds like a workaround for now, perhaps some modelbuilder or python to iterate over a grid, extract/isolate the drainage within, buffer, dissolve and then merge at the end into your geodatabase... that is assuming that the imported buffers don't go silly when imported - which would show that there is some geodatabase setting that's gone horribly wrong.